# Maximum value in 2D array (Processing)

Tags: arrays

I would like to find the maximum value within an array of integers (in Processing). I am familiar with the max() command, but it appears to only work for one-dimensional arrays. Does anybody have suggestions as to how I could efficiently find the maximum for a two-dimensional array?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Like I said in the post I'm using Processing.

Comment: wow, had never heard of that one before, learnt something new

Comment: In computer science it is considered very similar to Java, essentially a subcategory of Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what language you're using, but you could translate this to your language:

```
function findMaxOfArr(arr) {
    var rowMax=[];
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        rowMax.push(max(arr[i]));
    }
    return max(rowMax);
}
```

It first finds the maximum value of each row and stores it in a new array, then it finds the maximum value of that and returns it. You get the idea.